# Kann jemand mir bitte erklären, wo der Unterschied zwischen „Steigen“ und „Ansteigen“ liegt?

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

Kann jemand mir bitte erklären, wo der Unterschied zwischen „Steigen“ und „Ansteigen“ liegt ?

z.B : die Preise steigen / die Preise steigen an

Meiner Meinung nach bedeuten beide das Gleiche z.B die Preise sind angestiegen / die Preise sind gestiegen

Comment: Meiner Meinung Nach bedeuten die beide gleich z.B die Preise sind angestiegen / die Preise sind gestiegen .

Comment: @Marwan Bitte füge spezifische Beispiele Deiner Frage hinzu, anstatt in Kommentaren.

Answer (score 4):

Wie so oft in der deutschen Sprache können die genannten Worte verschiedene Bedeutungen haben. Und sie überlappen sich in einigen dieser Bedeutungen.

So kann zum Beispiel ein Ballon steigen, aber eher nicht ansteigen.

Ich kann auch eine Treppe steigen, aber nicht eine Treppe ansteigen.

Umgekehrt kann eine Treppe sowohl ansteigen als auch steigen.

Steigen hat in diesem (ersten) Beispiel die Bedeutung einer aktiven Tätigkeit vs. eine Zustandsbeschreibung oder eher passive Veränderung von aussen im zweiten Fall.

TL;DR nur weil EINE von vielen Bedeutungen zweier Worte zufällig identisch ist, sind nicht beide Worte identisch.

Comment: Mir ist jetzt klar :) .. vielen Dank

Comment: @Marwan Vielleicht als Trost: Es geht hier nicht um Unterscheidungen der Bedeutung (Semantik). Vielmehr geht es hier um Fragen des praktischen Einsatzes von Wörtern (Pragmatik): In welchen Kontexten wird welches Wort ***üblicherweise*** verwendet, und wo fände die Sprechergemeinschaft die Verwendung eher seltsam? Diese Dinge wandeln sich aber. Wenn genügend Leute genügend oft sagen: *Die Luftballons steigen an*, dann fängt es an, normal zu klingen. Solche Dinge passieren. Vor 30 Jahren hat noch niemand gesagt "Etwas macht Sinn". Man sagte nur "Etwas hat Sinn" oder "ergibt Sinn".